# How can I configure load balancing in open shift using PODs?

Tags: openshift

[image: 1]

I am looking for balance the routes.

Answer (score 1):

Your Route points to a Service („gateway-api-service“). This Service will then automatically load balance to any Pod it selects.

In the OpenShift Console, open the Service and look at the „Pods“ tab to see which Pods the traffic is load balanced to.

Typically, you can then scale the target Pods by increasing the number of replicas in a specific Deployment.